dbus shows a registered service provided by a PID that doesn't exist?
Consider this:
> dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID string:org.gnome.keyring
method return time=1724158870.854936 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.19163 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   uint32 9720
> ps -lp 9720
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
> kill -0 9720
9720: No such process
> ps -axlww | fgrep -i keyring
1   XXXX  9722  9216   1   0 293296  3012 -      SLl  ?          0:23 gnome-keyring-daemon --replace --daemonize --components=pkcs11,secrets,gpg

How is this possible?
DBus 1.14.6 running under kernel 4.14.328 (if that's even relevant).
New observation: it looks like the service gets registered by the launcher before it forks off the daemon.
> gnome-keyring-daemon -r -d &
[4] 26812
** Message: Replacing daemon, using directory: /run/user/XXXX/keyring-nIw6b7
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/XXXX/keyring-nIw6b7
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/XXXX/keyring-nIw6b7/ssh
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/XXXX/keyring-nIw6b7/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=26818
> dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID string:org.gnome.keyring
method return time=1724239784.045804 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.19724 serial=3 reply_serial=2
   uint32 26812

Weird that dbus and GNOME_KEYRING_ID don't correspond but apparently that causes no issues for usual clients. I ran into this "issue" testing KeePassXC's "secret service" feature which wouldn't activate because pid 9720 was already providing the service.

Does a /proc/9720/status exist? (Specifically, is it accessible by exact path, with head /proc/9720/status, and if so, what does it contain?)

Nope, it doesn't. I'm adding some new observations to my OP.
